# Add table to frame in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

I am new to swing and I have just started working on it as apart of my class work. Do forgive me if the question is irrelevant.
I am trying to put a table with some data from data base on a frame. What i have done is that I have created a JFrame Form. This form is blank. Now i am trying to populate a table, put it on a scroll Pane and finally add this scroll pane to my frame.

I am able to display the table by creating a new frame from the current frame. But what i want is add the table to the current Jframe form.

Here is what I have done:

```
package com.air.form;
import com.air.db.Transaction;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;



public class FlightDetails extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /** Creates new form FlightDetails */

    public FlightDetails() {
        initComponents();
    }
     FlightDetails(String src,String dest) {
        initComponents();
        initialise(src,dest);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 603, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FlightDetails().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private void initialise(String src, String dest)
    {
        Transaction tn=new Transaction();
        try
        {


            ResultSet result = tn.ReturnFlightDetails(src,dest);
            ResultSetMetaData md = result.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

            Vector columns = new Vector(columnCount);

            //store column names
            for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
            columns.add(md.getColumnName(i));

            Vector data = new Vector();
            Vector row;

            //store row data
            while(result.next())

            {
                row = new Vector(columnCount);
                for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
                {
                    row.add(result.getString(i));
                }
                data.add(row);
            }
            JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (hard-code some data to represent the `ResultSet`).

Comment: `WARNING: Do NOT modify this code.`  WARNING, delete 5 line comments that sound laughable in broken code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JFrame` is a `Container` which has the [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) method to add `Component`s to it. Depending on the layout manager, you need to pass some constraints as well. I do not see any of such calls in your code. You just create a table, but does not add it to any container.

As this is homework, I just going to include some extra links:

- [Swing tutorial on panels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)
- [Swing tutorial on layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)